# ¿Existe un metodo de ordenamiento merge-sort que sea iterativo?

Tags: java, algoritmos, ordenamiento

He buscado,pero solo he encontrado merge-sort recursivo.El problema surge cuando los subarreglos resultan de tamaños diferentes.
Les muestro lo que he intentado:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] arreglo = {45,65,90,6,63,55,23,2,34,5,33,44,57,8,98,732};
    int n = arreglo.length;
    int p = n / 2;
    int s = 0 ,j = 0,k = 0;
    for(j = 1 ; j < n; j=2*j){ 
        for(k = 0; k < n ; k++){
            s = Math.min(k+2*j, arreglo.length);
            merge(arreglo,k,(k+s)/2,s);
            System.out.println(k+"  "+(k + s)/2+"  "+s);
            k = s;
            
        }
    } 
    imprime(arreglo);
}
```

Aca esta el metodo merge que utilizo, este aparece en el libro Algorithms

```
    public static void merge(int[] A,int p,int q,int r){
    int[] arreglo = new int[q - p + 1];
    int[] arreglo2 = new int[r - q + 1];
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < arreglo.length - 1 ; i++){
        arreglo[i] = A[p + i];
    }
    for(j = 0; j < arreglo2.length - 1 ; j++){
        arreglo2[j] = A[q + j];
    }
    arreglo[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    arreglo2[j] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int cont1 = 0, cont2 = 0;
    for(int k = p ; k < r ; k++ ) {
            if(arreglo[cont1] <= arreglo2[cont2]){
                A[k] = arreglo[cont1];
                cont1++;            
            }else{
                A[k]  = arreglo2[cont2];
                cont2++;
            }               
    }
}
```

Por ultimo un metodo que imprime un arreglo

```
public static void imprime(int[] arreglo){
    for(int i:arreglo){
        System.out.print(i+ " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir un ejemplo del resultado final que desearías obtener?

Comment: que el arreglo que le entrego aparezca ordenado